# Call method of object within function

Tags: javascript, object

I know how to call a method from an object i.e. the following if `myObj.objMethod` is called it will return string.

```
myObj = {
  objProperty: 'string',
  objMethod: function() {
    return this.objProperty
  }
}
```

However, I am attempting the [following code wars exercise](https://www.codewars.com/kata/fix-my-method/train/javascript) and cannot figure out what needs to be done. It looks like they want the function to be called within itself. To do this i have tried using `arguments.callee.call(MyObject.objMethod())` but, as expected this exceeds the max call stack. Has anyone got any idea if this is possible to call a method of an object of a function, from within that function?

Here is (one of) my attempt(s) below:

```
function myFunction() {

  var MyObject = {
    objProperty: "string",
    objMethod: function() {
      return this.objProperty;
    }
  }

  return arguments.callee.call(MyObject.objMethod());

};
```

Here are the code wars instructions:

> Property objMethod should be called by myFunction.
>
> Can you fix the syntax so myFunction will be working again? Please
>   check things like braces, commas, and letter case.

and here is the original code provided:

```
function myFunction() {
  var MyObject = {
    objProperty: "string",
    objMethod: function() {
      return myObject.objProperty;
        }
  }

  return myObject.Objmethod();
};
```

Comment: `return MyObject.objMethod();`

Comment: @MirkoVukušić i tried that firstly, but didn't work

Comment: In your linked example you have cases wrong. You wrote `return myObject.Objmethod();` ... note wrong casing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your solution

```
function myFunction() {
  var MyObject = {
    objProperty: "string",
    objMethod: function() {
      return MyObject.objProperty;
    }
  }

  return MyObject;
};
```

The problem statement is

> Property objMethod should be called by myFunction.

It passes all the tests.

Comment: yeah, that was it! ok, guess i misunderstood what they were looking for a bit

Comment: This is correct answer to pass the test. However, please note that your initial problem was a lot of typos in your code. You would probably come to this conclusion yourself if you were able to run your own code. In example: 1) you were missisng a comma after `objProperty: "string"`, 2) you called `myObject.Objmethod();` and object was `MyObject` and method was `objMethod`, etc.

Comment: @MirkoVukušić That was the actual problem statement. One had to fix the errors in it.

Comment: @ClydeLobo I'm not questioning correct/best answer on this. It's definitely yours. I just wanted to make sure he understands where he was wrong. Because if he just copied your code into the test he might think only issue was to return `MyObject` instead of `MyObject.objMethod` and he would have missed all the other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you look at the test and what it is expecting. The test is expecting to be able to reference the object, not one particular property.

```
return MyObject;
```